# Dismissing dialog inside Asynctask triggered IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialog, illegalargumentexception

I've been using dialog for the `Asynctask` progress to show. By doing this, I initialized it inside `onPreExecute` and dismissed it in `onPostExecute`. I'm not sure what went wrong when I placed a condition to dismiss only if it's not null and it's showing but still triggered `IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager`

Here's the code:

> ```
>   public class SampleTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
>         public ProgressDialog pDialog;
>         @Override
>         protected void onPreExecute() {
>             super.onPreExecute();
>             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SampleActivity.this);
>             pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
>             pDialog.setCancelable(false);
>             pDialog.show();
>         }
>         @Override
>         protected String doInBackground(String... path) {
>             .
>             .
>             .
>         }
>         @Override
>         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>             super.onPostExecute(null);
>             if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
>                 pDialog.dismiss();
>             }
>             .
>             .
>             .
>         }
>     }
> ```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538282/view-not-attached-to-window-manager-dialog-dismiss) similar solution but would it differ if I place `null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()` together in the same condition?

Comment: code is write i think

Comment: remove super.onPostExecute(null);

Comment: did you rotating your phone? if yes try handle `configChanges` for that activity. And also try this `protected void onCancelled() {if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {              pDialog.dismiss();
}
    };`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998616/illegalargumentexception-why

Comment: this normally happens when configChanges or Activity is finished/destroyed before ProgressDialog.dismiss() is called

Comment: What is the downvote for? I have stated the snippet. Furthermore, there's no landscape for my app so rotation is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you only accept the android view in main UI Thread. [Read this link for more detail](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) So when you call `pDialog.dismiss();` in `onPostExecute(String)`, it run on another thread so android throw new `IllegalArgumentException`. I have some solution for you and hope that help:
1. I alway use this solution but it not good at all:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO something you would like to do with Android UI.
    }
};
handler.post(runable);
```

The Handler will create a new thread to run on UI Thread so you can work with Android UI.
2. Sometime I try to use an `interface`. It more effective than the solution above however, of course, it make me spend more effort.

Comment: Actually `Asynctask` itself is in another thread so basically, placing the dialog inside it is different in my main UI thread.

Comment: So, can my solution help you?