# Is there a way to determine whether it is possible to call a dialog.dismiss() without empty try-catch block?

Tags: java, android, api, scala, architecture

I am getting the well known `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager`. The currently [known solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745061/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-view-not-attached-to-window-manager) is to ignore the error using empty try-catch block. But is it there a more programmer friendly solution? E.g.

```
if (dialog.isAttached())
  dialog.dismiss();
```

Of course, better would be if the Android SDK would have a not failing function (because why the API should fail if it is impossible to avoid it??):

```
dialog.tryDismiss();
```

Or is the empty try-catch block architectonically justifiable? Or is it just a workaround for a bad or incomplete API?

Answer (score 2):

I always use:

```
if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
  dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Not working if you click `Home` button during the time the dialog is shown (it is a progress dialog) and the action finishes (the dialog is going to be dismissed) when the activity is no longer visible.

Comment: Sorry, but I just tried what you said in my application (Upload a picture and while the dialog is showing, press home button and wait for the action to finish (it shows a toast message). No exception at all.

Comment: Hmm, strange. The same thing gives me exception on Android 2.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())dialog.dismiss();
```

better you **dismiss dialog** before activity disappears/closes...that means in onPause() and onDestroy() event too..