# Deezer SDK for Android, how to give access_token to a DeezerRequest?

Tags: java, android, deezer

I'm using JAVA Android SDK to develop a Deezer application.
I already have managed to log in with a Deezer method (a pop-up appear that allow the user to log with his deezer or facebook account).

But now I'd like to access the user data (name / id ...) for future use. I'm currently using

```
DeezerRequest request_name = new DeezerRequest("/user/me");
```

But the application throw an exception, asking for the access_token. I have it but I can't figure how to give it to the request (and the deezer dev site is not really helpful as he assume that you know what to do with it)

I can post more code if it's helpful.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After login correctly this is the code that i use (taken from the sample Deezer app that is in your sdk zip files)

In your Activity:

```
private RequestListener userRequestListenerHandler = new UserRequestHandler();

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

....

searchUser();
}

public void searchUser(){

    AsyncDeezerTask searchAsyncUser = new AsyncDeezerTaskWithDialog(this,  deezerConnect, userRequestListenerHandler);
        DeezerRequest request = new DeezerRequest("user/me");
        searchAsyncUser.execute(request);

}

public void searchUserFinish(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String name = user.getFirstname();
        Sring lastname = user.getLastname();
        //... other user data
        }


private class UserRequestHandler implements RequestListener{

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try{


                User user = new DeezerDataReader<User>(User.class).read(response);

                searchUserFinish(user);

            }catch (IllegalStateException e){
                handleError(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onDeezerError(DeezerError e, Object arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handleError(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handleError(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handleError(e);

        }

        @Override
        public void onOAuthException(OAuthException e, Object arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handleError(e);
        }

    }

public void handleError(Error e){
Toast.maketext(this,e,Toast.Length_Short).show();
}
```

THE ASYNC DEEZER TASK

```
public class AsyncDeezerTaskWithDialog extends AsyncDeezerTask {
    /** Progress dialog to show user that the request is beeing processed. */
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    /**
     * Simply creates an Deezer task with a dialog.
     * @param context the context used to create the dialog into.
     * @param deezerConnect the DeezerConnect object used to connect to Deezer web services.
     * @param listener the request listener.
     */
    public AsyncDeezerTaskWithDialog(Context context, DeezerConnect deezerConnect,
            RequestListener listener ) {
        super(deezerConnect, listener );
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog( context );
        progressDialog.setCancelable( true );
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener( new OnCancelHandler() );
    }//met

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage( "Contacting Deezer..." );
        progressDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }//met

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute( String s ) {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745061/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-view-not-attached-to-window-manager
        try {
            if( progressDialog.isShowing() ) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }//if
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            //can happen sometimes, and nothing to get against it
        }//catch
        super.onPostExecute( s );
    }//met

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745061/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-view-not-attached-to-window-manager
        try {
            if ( progressDialog.isShowing() ) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }//if
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            //can happen sometimes, and nothing to get against it
        }//catch
        super.onCancelled();
    }//met

    private class OnCancelHandler implements OnCancelListener {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            cancel( true );
        }//met
    }//inner class
}//class
```

DEEZER DATA READER CLASS

```
public class DeezerDataReader<T extends Object> {

    /** Class to pass to the Gson parser to create POJOs. */
    private Class<T> clazz = null;

    /** Creates a reader. 
     * @param clazz class to pass to the Gson parser to create POJOs. 
     * */
    public DeezerDataReader( Class<T> clazz ) {
        if( clazz == null ){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Clazz can't be null." );
        }//if
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }//cons

    /**
     * DAO method to read (deserialize) data from a json string.
     * @param json the json string to deserialize.
     * @return a list of typed data from Deezer. The list can't be null, but may be empty.
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the parser encounters an error in json format.
     */
    public T read( String json ) throws IllegalStateException {
        Gson gson = new Gson(); 
        JsonObject object = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
        return gson.fromJson( object, clazz );
    }//met

}//met
```

Comment: Nop, still the same problem :/        
06-12 10:33:13.710: W/userRequesthandler / onOAuthException(4558): com.deezer.sdk.OAuthException: msg=An active access token must be used to query information about the current user, type=, code=0

Comment: I think I have to add something to deezerConnect (via a bundle or something) but I don't know what and how ^^'

Answer (score 1):

Great, someone helped me to link the access token to the deezerConnect :

```
/** DeezerConnect object used for auhtentification or request. */
private DeezerConnect deezerConnect = new DeezerConnectImpl(APP_ID);
//----
deezerConnect.setAccessToken(getApplicationContext(), access_token);
```

The access token is gotten thanks to

```
deezerConnect.authorize(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS,
            new LoginDialogHandler());

//----
private class LoginDialogHandler implements DialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(final Bundle values) {

        MainActivity.access_token = values.getString("access_token");
    }
//----
}
```

Comment: Can we log in automatically to deezer without user interaction ?