# how to prevent activity from stopping?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

i need to do a long time job (updating a lot of `sql` tables) in `onstop` override of an activity but when i close that activity my apps stops working for several seconds . i tried to use `AsyncTask` but in that time i get error an error for dialog.dismiss() method in onPostExecute that it says can't attach the dialog to the window ! also i have tried to use services but this method have to be called several times and starting and stopping that service each time didn't work correctly !

i am just mixed up! could you help me with this plz! thanks in advance! :)

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538282/view-not-attached-to-window-manager-dialog-dismiss)

Comment: Service is certainly the way to go here, but it's hard to suggest you anything since you haven't described your actual problem in the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntentService is perfect for such tasks:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

> i have tried to use services but this method have to be called several
>   times and starting and stopping that service each time didn't work
>   correctly !

you simply send jobs to your IntentService, it will take care of initialization and destruction, no need to implement full blown Service.