# IllegalArgumentException - WindowManagerGlobal.java

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

I catch many crashes in crashlitycs, but I dont know - where did these crashes? [image]
Help please, becouse its big problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [sourcecode](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/WindowManagerGlobal.java#L386).

I believe it can happen if you try to close your dialog and his parent activity simultaneous. So the WindowManager tries to remove a view which does not exists any more (already removed).

Look also at this Question: [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745061/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-view-not-attached-to-window-manager)

Answer (score 2):

Your error occur (As per my opinion or my knowledge) when dismissing progress dialog not checking whether it is showing or not. So you must have to do below:-

```
if (!Activity.this.isFinishing() && mProgressDialog != null) {
    if(mProgressDialog.isShowing())
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

So you must have to check this to all your activity or fragment.