# Error on Android AsyncTask's OnCancelled()

Tags: android, xamarin

I found an error in AsyncTask's `OnCancelled()` method and the error is below:

> Exception of type 'Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException' was thrown.
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41b1e790 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} not attached to window manager

Code I am using inside `OnCancelled()` is:

```
if (progressDialog != null)
{
   if (progressDialog.IsShowing == true)
      progressDialog.Dismiss();
 }
```

Comment: put your `AsyncTask` code.

Comment: Sorry @Rustam i can't share my code with you due to some privacy..
I caught the above exception in OnCancelled() method so definitely the error will be inside it and and due to the above code which i mentioned

Comment: hmmm i m sure error is due to other portion of your code than what you posted.

Comment: No @Rustam i used try/catch statement inside OnCancelled() method

Comment: @Rustam i got my ansswer, it is because the activity is destroyed where the progressDialog is rendered.
Thanks for your response...

Answer (score 1):

This happens if your view was already destroyed by the time the AsyncTask's onCancelled event has fired. [Look at this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745061/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-view-not-attached-to-window-manager)

Comment: you are correct, but i actually want to know the solution for it i.e. 
how can i avoid this type of exception

Comment: Read the solutions to the question in the link I've added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Eran for you quick response