# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - dialog.dismiss

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception, dismiss

I am getting this error in my published application, only clients receive this error. I already tried several times to replicate the same mistake however unsuccessfully.
I also already tried to use the below code at all locations where there is a Dialog but also not solved.

```
if (dialog.isShowing ()) {
    dialog.dismiss ();
}
```

**The error report**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{16faa139 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0} not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:412)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:338)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:122)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:522)
at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:504)

**at br.my.project.de.a(Unknown Source)
at br.my.project.de.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)**

at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Is dialog in activity or fragment ? When you dismiss dialog check if it is null or not

Comment: Hi @Piyush the dialog is in Activity

Comment: in `onDestroy()` method of activity just check if it is not null then cancel the dialog and make its object `null`.

Comment: @Piyush Okay, I'll try it! but it has some way to replicate this error in development mode?

Answer (score 5):

I could see that you are trying to dismiss a ProgressDialog on the postExecute of an AsyncTask. This in itself is a good practice but is sometimes buggy, I kind of experienced this also before especially while you're showing the ProgressDialog and suddenly rotate the view.

A solution I've found to fix this is below:

You will need these function to handle the proper dismissal and avoid crashes.

```
private void dismissProgressDialog(ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
            if (progressDialog != null) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {

                    //get the Context object that was used to create the dialog
                    Context context = ((ContextWrapper) progressDialog.getContext()).getBaseContext();

                    // if the Context used here was an activity AND it hasn't been finished or destroyed
                    // then dismiss it
                    if (context instanceof Activity) {

                        // Api >=17
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                            if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing() && !((Activity) context).isDestroyed()) {
                                dismissWithExceptionHandling(progressDialog);
                            }
                        } else {

                            // Api < 17. Unfortunately cannot check for isDestroyed()
                            if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
                                dismissWithExceptionHandling(progressDialog);
                            }
                        }
                    } else
                        // if the Context used wasn't an Activity, then dismiss it too
                        dismissWithExceptionHandling(progressDialog);
                }
                progressDialog = null;
            }
        }


public void dismissWithExceptionHandling(ProgressDialog dialog) {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // Do nothing.
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                // Do nothing.
            } finally {
                dialog = null;
            }
        }
```

On your AsyncTask's onPostExecute implement the function.

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean b) {
     // pass in the progressDialog as a parameter to the method
     dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog);
 }
```

Comment: This seems to be a link to an answer that you had found:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34651013/8473143

Answer (score 2):

```
fun Activity?.dismissDialog(dialog: Dialog?) {
    if (isActivityActive()) {
        dialog?.apply {
            if (isShowing) dismiss()
        }
    }
}


fun Activity?.isActivityActive(): Boolean {
    return null != this && !isFinishing && !isDestroyed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling dismiss on a dialog that is currently not being shown anymore. As in: your Activity/Fragment is possibly already destroyed when you call dismiss.

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in your activity's

> onStop()

method.When anybody presses the home button and if dialog is opened than this error will come. Because on click of home button onPause() and onStop() method calls.Hope this helps.

```
 if (dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing ()) {
          dialog.dismiss ();
             }
```

Comment: Not working. I've already called `dismiss` in the `onPause`.